# Array classes in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to make an array class and link it with a PHP file as follows:

```
    <?php  
    $myarray=array('1','2','3');
    array1_class=new array_class($myarray);
```

And I want to try to create a class that I can put my array in and then call them as follows:

```
    array1_class->data[1]; // It should display '2' for example
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Why not just `$myarray[2]`?

Comment: public __construct($data) {
$this->data = $data;
}

Comment: you do know there is an array class in php already? http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question owner has stated in commets it is a poor question and they don't know why they originally asked it. The question has a more efficient and useful answer in that PHP already naturally provides the intended usability requested in the question, without the performance and effort overhead of a specialist `class`.

Comment: but i just made a detailed answer for him :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class MyLameArray
{
    /** @var array $data */
    public $data;

   /**
    * @param array $data
    */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

   /**
    * @param string $key
    * @param mixed $value
    * @return bool
    */ 
    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

   /**
    * @param string $key
    * @return mixed|null
    */ 
    public function get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
    }

   /**
    * @param string $key
    * @return bool
    */ 
    public function has($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}
```

which you can then use like this

```
$data = array(
    'food' => 'fried chicken',
);
$x = new MyLameArray($data);

echo $x->has('fail') ? 'fail var set' : 'no fail var set';
echo "\n";
echo $x->has('food') ? 'food var set' : 'no food var set';
echo 'food is set to '.$x->get('food');
echo "\n";
$x->set('food', 'burger');
echo $x->data['food'];
```

see it here: https://3v4l.org/P9cdD

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
class array_class {
    public $data;
    function __construct(array $arr) {
        $this->data = $arr;
    }
}
```

However, what would be the use ?
It works exactly like an array (since it's an array in an object) but with increased complexity and verbosity and decreased perfomance.
What's the use of... *that* ?

Comment: What's with the shouting ? I know there is such a class, why is it relevant ? The OP explicitly asks about a way to **create** a class, not adding the array behaviour to an already existing class by making it to extend arrayClass...

Comment: it wasn't shouting, it was my way of attempting italics to emphasise tone of voice ;-p

Comment: how did YOU get the italics?

Comment: *Italics* are obtained by writing between '*' characters.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem and there is non sense about my question :P. Whatever, the reason I've asked this it was because I have a configuration.txt and I want to put the information as an array. The function file_get_content() and explode() may help in this. Newbie question sorry :P